# Failed to establish connection to server

Tags: azure-synapse

After spinning up our dedicated sql pool we receive the following message while creating a default table. "**Failed to establish connection to server**".

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Edit. Connecting to sql studio I am able to create tables, however, synapse studio just can't seem to connect. It did end up working for about 5 sec via synapse studio but once I paused/resumed the pool it broke once again.

Edit2: Removed the image. Thanks for the feedback Rob, appreciate it. Table code below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] (    col1 int NOT NULL ) WITH (   DISTRIBUTION = HASH (col1),    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX ) GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are proper troubleshoot steps given by Microsoft for **"Failed to establish connection to server"** error. Please follow the same given steps mentioned below to resolve the issue.

1. Open the **"Diagnostic Info"** panel, select the **"Download Diagnostic"** button. Keep the downloaded information for error reporting. You can instead, copy the **"Session ID"** and attach it when opening the support ticket.

[image]

2. Press `F12` in your browser to open "Developer Tools" (DevTools).
3. In the "Developer Tools" window, switch to the "Network" panel. Select the "Clear" button on the toolbar in "Network" panel if necessary. Make sure "Disable cache" in "Network" panel is checked.
4. Retry the operation you performed in Azure Synapse Studio. You may see new items shown in the "Network" list in "Developer Tools". Note your current system time to provide in the support ticket.

[image]

5. Find the item whose Url column matches the following pattern:

```
https://[*A*]-ondemand.database.windows.net:1443/databases/[*B*]/query?api-version=2018-08-01-preview&application=ArcadiaSqlOnDemandExplorer
```

- Where `[A]` is your workspace name, and `"-ondemand"` could be `"-sqlod"` and where `[B]` should be a **database name**, such as "master". There should be at most two items with the same URL value but different method values; OPTIONS and POST. Check whether these two items have "200" or "20x" under the status column, where "x" could be any single digit.

6. If either one of them has something other than "20x" and:

- Status starts with "(failed)", either widen the "Status" column or hover your pointer over the status text to see the complete text. Include the text and/or screenshot when opening the support ticket.

[image]

```
- If you see ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED and you created your workspace within 10 minutes, wait for 10 minutes and retry to see whether the problem still exists.
- If you see ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED or ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED, it may indicate your PC network connection is having issues. Check your network connection and retry the operation.
- If you see ERR_CONNECTION_RESET, ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR or other error codes containing "SSL", it may indicate your local SSL configuration is having issues, or your network administrator has blocked access to the serverless SQL pool server. Open a support ticket and attach the error code in the description.
- If you see ERR_NETWORK_ACCESS_DENIED, you may need to check with the administrator on whether your local firewall policy has blocked access to either *.database.windows.net domain, or remote port 1443.
```

Optionally, try the same operation immediately on a different machine and/or network environment to rule out a network configuration issue on your PC.

- Status is "40x", "50x", or other numbers, select on the item(s) to see the details. You should see the item details to the right. Find the "Response Header" section; then check whether an item named "access-control-allow-origin" exists. If so, check whether it has one of the following values:

  - `*` (single asterisk)
  - https://web.azuresynapse.net/ (or other value that the text in your browser address bar starts with)

7. If the response header contains one of the above values, it means we should have already collected the failure information. You can open a support ticket if needed, and optionally attach the screenshot of the item details.
8. If you can't see the header, or the header does not have one of the values listed above, attach a screenshot of the item details when you open the ticket.

[image]

If the steps above do not solve your issue, you may need to open a support ticket. When submitting your support ticket, include the "Session ID" or "Diagnostic Info" downloaded at the beginning of this guide.

When reporting the issue, you may optionally take a screenshot of your "Console" tab in the "Developer Tools" and attach it to the support ticket. Scroll the content and take more than one screenshot if necessary to capture the entire message.

[image]

If you're attaching screenshots, provide the time (or an estimated time range) of when you took the screenshots. It will help us when looking into the problem.

Certain browsers support showing timestamps in the "Console" tab. For Chromium Edge/Chrome, open the "Settings" dialog in "Developer Tools", and check "Show timestamps" in "Preferences" tab.

[image]

[image]

Original content by Microsoft: [Synapse Studio troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/troubleshoot/troubleshoot-synapse-studio#symptom-2)